# how to get the smallest possible delay on a live HLS stream to a Google cast?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I am streaming a live HLS buffer with ffmpeg and I want to play it back on a Chromecast device with the lowest latency possible.

Best result I have so far is with that command:
`ffmpeg -y -f x11grab -video_size 1280x720 -i :99 -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -fflags nobuffer -vcodec libx264 -r 24 -preset superfast -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 6 -hls_list_size 5 -hls_time 0 -strict -2 video/test.m3u8`

The main issue I have is that it seems that my Google cast has a bigger buffer than when I try with VLC with a buffer of size 0, 3 seconds difference. Is there a way to make sure the device uses the smallest buffer size as possible?

I looked at the Cast reference and I haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [blog](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/tips-and-tricks-to-improve-your-chromecast-experience/), if videos are choppy or suffering from constant buffering interruptions, it is recommended that you reduce your video playback settings. This can be done in the Chromecast options in the upper-right-hand corner of your Chrome browser. Click the box, select Options, and reduce your streaming to Standard (480p). The video quality will take a small hit, but it should be watchable, with little to no interruption. You may also check this [page](https://cord-cutters.gadgethacks.com/how-to/get-your-chromecast-stop-lagging-0150430/) for more recommendations.